# Discord.py rewrite when trying to delete a channel the ".delete()" command gives an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been working on a discord bot for a while now, but I've came across a problem.
Creating a channel (Ticket) goes just fine, but when I want to delete the certain channel it still closes all even though I made an if statement:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('!close'):
    close = message.channel.id
    if close == '521992786187255818' or close == '525730667607228426' or close ==... (etc):
        await message.channel.send("This command is only allowed in a ticket channel!")
    elif close != '521992786187255818' or close != '525730667607228426' or close !=...(etc):
        await message.channel.delete(reason='Ticket Closed')
```

I've tried anything I could think of: Making the channels which I don't want it to close into a list.

So the problem is: I want the !close command to only close channels which I haven't listed. But when I try it in a listed channel (A channel I entered in the if statement) It still closes it.

I hope I can get an answer! 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rewrite branch, [all ids are integers, not strings](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#snowflakes-are-int).  Change your code to

```
non_ticket_channels = [521992786187255818, 525730667607228426, ...]

if close in non_ticket_channels:
    ...
else:
    ...
```